# grunt-cucumber not running step_definitions

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, cucumberjs

I'm trying to create a grunt task to run cucumber.js tests. The tests are organized in feature "areas" within my project eg:

```
project_root
    --test
        --spec-e2e
            --home_Page
                --features
                --step_definitions
```

From my project's node_modules dir I can run cucumber.js manually and all is well:

```
$ node cucumber.js ../../../test/spec-e2e/home_Page/features/
```

Output:

```
1 scenario (1 passed)
3 steps (3 passed)
```

I cannot seem to get the grunt-cucumber task configured properly to recreate the same result.
In my Gruntfile.js I have the following configuration:

```
 // Cucumber test runner
    cucumberjs: {
      src: 'test/spec-e2e/home_Page/features',
      options: {
        steps: 'test/spec-e2e/home_Page/features/step_definitions',
        format: 'pretty'
      }
    }
    ...
//Register task
grunt.registerTask('cucumber', ['cucumberjs']);
```

Running `$ grunt cucumber` allows just outputs:

```
$ Running "cucumberjs:src" (cucumberjs) task

$ Done, without errors.
```

So I'm not receiving any errors or cucumber summary output. If I purposely edit one of my step_definitions to fail the result is always the same. Can someone tell me how to configure this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using the plugin by st9pepper? if so, i wouldn't recommend it, because st9pepper doesnt seem to maintain his modules (grunt-jasmine-node is another one). i would use this one: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-cucumberjs, which seems to be better maintained, and probably better to use. should probably solve your issue too

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:**

Please go through the below doc :

[Grunt cucumber js docs](https://github.com/s9tpepper/grunt-cucumber-js)

**This code works for me :**

```
     grunt.initConfig({
           cucumberjs: {
                    all: {
                        src: 'features',
                        options: {
                            backtrace: true,
                            useShortStackTraces: false,
                            format: "json:<path where want to write json report>",
                            steps: 'features',
                            tags: grunt.option('feature')

                        }
                    }   
        });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['cucumberjs:all']);
```